# Override Google map inline styles with css

Tags: css, google-maps

I am trying to override the New Google Maps inline style so to apply my own with CSS.
I cannot use Jquery because it will conflict with Mootools (I m using Joomla).

The problem is that the upperleft "infowindow" covers a big part of the map (plus the point bubble), and I want to limit it a bit as the 280px given width is too much.

using firebug I find this:

```
<div id="featureListPanel" class="b0t70b-haAclf" style="display: block; z-index: 0; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 144px; width: 280px;"
```

but my style cannot ovveride it:

```
div#featureListPanel [style] {width: 271px !important;}
```

How can I solve this?

PS. I even tried this:

```
body div[class*="b0t70b-haAclf"] {width: 271px !important;}
```

No luck.. Does Google Maps Api prevent me to touch it with CSS or what?

EDIT: There's an image to help you understand what I mean. Surrounded in red is the infowindow mentioned.
[image: Annoing Google Infowindow]

Comment: Is this an embedded(in an iframe) map created via mapsengine?

Comment: @Dr.Molle sorry, I wasn't notified that you replied me! Yes, it is embedded in an iframe copied from gmaps. I edited the post with an image to help readers get what I mean.

Comment: there is no way to override these styles from the parent page

Answer (score 0):

`div#featureListPanel [style] {width: 271px !important;}` [style] is not valid way of css

So simply use this:

```
div#featureListPanel {width: 271px !important;}
```

if even don't work try this

```
body div#featureListPanel [style] {width: 271px !important;}
```

Comment: Well, the [style] is an attribute selector. Why it is not valid?